# How can I iterate a structure twice through a function, but with different parameters each time, without using two for loops in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration, concatenation

I'm working with a huge system, so I can't make any changes to the function.

My goal is to run x through the function with a certain parameter (yield/return the results) and then run x through the same function but with a different parameter (and yield/return the second results). Preferably less lengthy solution than what I have now.

I've tried to use zip() but get a tuple has no attribute error. I know C has a concat function when it comes to iterating.

```
def function():

    # returns "1 2 3"
    for x in pdm.function(param1): 
        yield {
            x.info1
            # more info 2 -7 
            x.info8
            }

    # returns "a" 
    for x in pdm.function(param2): 
        yield {
            x.info1
            # more info 2 -7 
            x.info8
            }
```

This returns what I need, "1 2 3 a" but is long and I want to learn how to iterate it better.

I can't do `for x, y in pdm.function(param1):` because they need to have different params.

I know I can also follow DRY and make the inside a function. Which would reduce the lines I have by half, but also add another function to the huge code base already existing:

```
def printwords(x):
        yield {
            x.info1
            # more info 2 -7 
            x.info8
            }
```

Ideally if something like this exists to concatenate that would be the answer I'm looking for:

```
for x in pdm.function(param1) and x in pdm.function(param2): 
    yield {
        x.info1
        # more info 2 -7 
        x.info8
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: One way to make one nested for loop is `for f in [pdm.function(param1), pdm.function(param2)]: for x in f: ...`

Comment: Without nesting `for x in [*pdm.function(param1), *pdm.function(param2)]: ...` would work depending on what `pdm.function()` returns

Comment: @OsmanMamun I think a nested for loop would just make it slower than having two separate for loops. I tried out your second suggestion, it didn't work with the "*" so I took those out but it looks like it didn't work because "AttributeError object has no attribute info". I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
params = [param1, param2]
for p in params:
    for x in pdm.function(p):......
```

Comment: Double for loop would be a bit slower but would work. Is there any way to concatenate them?

Comment: This will not be any slower, at least not in any significant way. Iterating over `params` is going to take approximately the same amount of time it would take to concatenate the two iterables.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `itertools.chain`.

```
from itertools import chain

for x in chain(pdm.function(param1), pdm.function(param2)):
    yield x
```

But I want to comment on your use of 'slower' as a meaningful comparison.

Unless you are also benchmarking your code or have worked out the complexity of the code using big O or big Θ analysis, then you really can't say that two `for`-loops in sequence is 'slow', or that a nested `for`-loop where the outer loop only runs twice is 'slower' than your initial code with sequential `for`-loops.  Without complexity analysis and benchmarking, you are simply inferring performance characteristics from language syntax. If you're doing that, you will be often surprised.  Who knows what optimizations are made once the source code is turned into bytecode and run on the python virtual machine!

More succinct or compact code doesn't always produce more efficient code.